# docker-compose and listing volume contents

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Maybe I'm just not understanding correctly but I'm trying to visually verify that I have used volumes properly.

In my docker-compose I'd have something like

```
some-project:
  volumes:
   - /some-local-path/some-folder:/v-test
```

I can verify it's contents via "ls -la /some-local-path/some-folder"

In some-projects Dockerfile I'd have something like

```
  RUN ls -la /v-test
```

which returns 'No such file or directory"

Is this the correct way to use it? If so, why can't I view the contents from inside the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in the `Dockerfile` runs before anything outside the `build:` block in the `docker-compose.yml` file is considered.  The image build doesn't see volumes or environment variables that get declared only in `docker-compose.yml`, and it can't access other services.

In your example, *first* the `Dockerfile` tries to `ls` the directory, *then* Compose will start the container with the bind mount.

If you're just doing this for verification, you can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) a container with most of its settings from the `docker-compose.yml` file, but an alternate command:

```sh
docker-compose run some-project \
  ls -la /v-test
```

(Doing this requires that the image's `CMD` is a well-formed shell command; either it has no `ENTRYPOINT` or the `ENTRYPOINT` is a wrapper script that ends in `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.  If you only have `ENTRYPOINT`, change it to `CMD`; if you've split the command across both directives, consolidate it into a single `CMD` line.)

Comment: Is there a way to use the volume inside the Dockerfile if it is created in the docker-compose?

Comment: No.  It doesn't exist yet, and it'd be possible to mount different volumes on the same mount point in multiple containers based on the same image.  (Container applications tend to work better if you can design them to not need volumes at all.)